# Calculate end time from inputted date and time pickers

Tags: java, android, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am trying to create an end time based on a date and time a user has selected from pickers. Does anyone know if this is possible to calculate or work with date and time selected from pickers?

This is the code that has been tried.. it currently gets the current date and time not the users selection from the pickers.

These are the pickers below:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_line);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.durationtextView);
    dateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn);
    VerifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
    tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonddate);

    mCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    day = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);



    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(CreateLine.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    monthOfYear = monthOfYear +1;
                    String Sd = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
                    tv.setText(Sd);

                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });

    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_displayTPD);
    Button displayTDPButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_displayTPD);
    displayTDPButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new TimePickerDialog(CreateLine.this, onTimeSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
        }

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                String St = String.valueOf(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                display.setText(St);
            }
        };
```

This is the calculation for the end time

```
   dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dateButton.setText(date.toString());

                    // Creates an instance of current DateTime which represents the
                    // current date time.
                    //DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
                    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, 12, 0, 0, 11);

                    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");
                    String formattedtime = fmt.print(dateTime);
                    dateButton.setText(formattedtime);

                    // Plus some hours, minutes, and seconds to the original DateTime.
                    DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");

                    DateTime dateTime1 = dateTime.plusHours(timeadded);
                    String endtimecalc = fmt2.print(dateTime1);
                    TextView endtime = (TextView) findViewById(endtimetextView);
                    endtime.setText(endtimecalc);


                }
            });


            VerifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String spinnerSelection = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
                    String spinnerSelection2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
                    String q = quantity.getText().toString();
                    String d = duration.getText().toString();

                    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
                    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");
                    String formattedtime = fmt.print(dateTime);
                    dateButton.setText(formattedtime);

                    // Plus some hours, minutes, and seconds to the original DateTime.
                    DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");

                    DateTime dateTime1 = dateTime.plusHours(timeadded);
                    String endtimecalc = fmt2.print(dateTime1);
                    TextView endtime = (TextView) findViewById(endtimetextView);
                    endtime.setText(endtimecalc);
```

This is  a screenshot of the intended outcome 'endtime'. The outcome is the date and time picked by the pickers and plus duration in hours should = endtime

[image: EndTime]

Comment: pickers 'pick', they don't calculate. you can of course do something like endtime is starttime.add(hours, 8) or something similar, if that is what you're looking for

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with end-time. Is it simply  "end-time = date + time" you are looking for? In that case I would suggest to read up on UTC calculations and I suppose you can simply add DateTime objects and get the result from that..

Comment: Please see image I have added, hopefully that explains it better

Answer (score 0):

**First convert date into millisecond date and then calculate time**

```
Date startDate = // Set start date
Date endDate   = // Set end date

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```

Comment: We are setting the start date from the picker based on what the user selects

Comment: Set user selected date to Date using simpledateformat and then follow my above code

Comment: how can I set the selected date when the variables are locally declared on the onclick method?

Comment: @Fionnuala please declare required variables globally

Comment: how do you declare "int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth" globally?

Comment: you there? Not sure how to do this